# How do you ONLY trigger a `set` operation when WPF `TextBox` content, and still support programmatic content changes via `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

## Scenario

1. Start the demo application with the Visual Studio debugger attached.
2. User types `a` into the text box.
3. Wait 2 seconds.
4. As expected, you will see the `set` operation on `TextBoxValue`

   - Which is confirmed by output in the *Debug* window.
5. You then see a `get` operation on `TextBoxValue`

   - I don't understand why the *getter* is being called when the code behind is not explicitly raising the  `PropertyChanged` event.

Output:

```
SET 03:45:57 5471 Property=TextBoxValue, Value=a
GET 03:45:57 5491 Property=TextBoxValue, Value=a
```

### Sample Code

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxValue, Delay=2000, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class ComboBoxDemo : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _textBoxValue;

    public ComboBoxDemo()
    {
        _textBoxValue = string.Empty;
         this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss ffff");
            Debug.WriteLine($"GET {time} Type=TextBoxValue, Value={_textBoxValue}");
            return _textBoxValue;
        }

        set
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss ffff");
            Debug.WriteLine($"SET {time} Type=TextBoxValue, Value={value}");
            _textBoxValue = value;

            // Note: the `PropertyChanged` event is not being raised
        }
    }
}
```

## Intended Behavior

My question is... **how do you achieve the following?**

1. when the user changes the `TextBox` content, only `set` operation is performed on `TextBoxValue` AND
2. when the value is changed programmatically, the `TextBox` will update to reflect the change

   - specifically: code behind changes `_textBoxValue` & raises `PropertyChanged` event for the `TextBoxValue` property

Setting the `TextBox`'s binding mode to `OneWayToSource` does result in only the `set` being called but:

- is the wrong solution, and
- understandably, raising the `PropertyChanged` event from the code behind will have no effect

Comment: _why the getter is being called when_ It seems because of two-way [binding mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.mode?view=netcore-3.1) You can try to use one way mode

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I’m surprised that I never noticed that a ‘get’ operation is called after a UI initiated content change. I always assumed it was the result of raising ‘PropertyChanged’ event in the code behind.

Comment: I don’t think OneWay binding will work as the content can be modified from both sides of the binding: the *Source* which is the ‘DataContext’ and the *Target* which is the ‘TextBox’.

Comment: What's wrong with the getter being called? A property is supposed to return the exact value that it was assigned before.

Comment: In this case the ‘set’ kicks off a long running operation (via a ‘Task’). When complete, the member field is updated and the change is propagated to the UI.  I completely agree that a getter being called is a normal behaviour. I have an alternative implementation... it just seemed strange: why would a ‘Set’ trigger a ‘Get’. The ‘TextBox’ already has the value... so why perform an unnecessary read on the ‘DataContext’?

Comment: You can't rely on the framework not calling the getter. It will whenever it updates the layout, for example if you scroll or change the position of the window. Kicking off long-running operations in property getters (and even setters) is a bad practice.